# HtmlUnit error using XPath functions number() and string()

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

Let's say inside an html page there are these three anchors.
Using htmlunit i want to get the numbers inside these anchors (as numbers not as text).

```
<a class="someclass" href="http://someaddress1.com">3.14</a>
<a class="someclass" href="http://someaddress2.com">1.22</a>
<a class="someclass" href="http://someaddress3.com">6.66</a>
```

The job has to be done by the following testXPath method :

```
public static void testXPath () {

  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  webClient.setCssEnabled(false);

  try {

        final HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("pageurl");

        String XPath="//a[@class='someclass']/number()";

        List<Object> list = (List<Object>) page.getByXPath(XPath);

        for (Objects : list) {
             System.out.println(s);
        }

  } catch (Exception e) {   
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

When i run this i get :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve XPath 
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: number
```

The same error occurs when i want to get only the href values (as String). In this case :

```
String XPath="//a[@class='someclass']/@href/string()";
```

But when,

```
String XPath="string(//a[@class='someclass']/@href)";
```

i get only the first href value `http://someaddress1.com`

---

I know i can get those numbers as string and then parse them as    Double

```
List<DomText> list = (List<DomText>) page.getByXPath("//a[@class='someclass']/text()");
for (DomText d : list) {
  System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).toString()));
}
```

and i can use .getValue() to get the hrefs

```
List<DomAttr> list = (List<DomAttr>) page.getByXPath("//a[@class='someclass']/@href");
for (DomAttr d : list) {
  System.out.println(list.get(i).getValue());
}
```

but that is not the case. I want to use XPath functions to do that (i'm guessing it's faster).

Comment: You could use the `number()` function (available in XPath 1.0, [see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number)) but as it returns only 1 value for the first node in the node-set, e.g in your case `number(//a[@class='someclass'])` returns `3.14`, you would have to loop on the links, with `//a[@class='someclass']` for example, and then call `number(.)` on each. Probably easier to do in your application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin said, this is an XPath 2.0 feature. HtmlUnit does not currently support XPath 2.0. This means you can not use that expression.

I would recommend to workaround it by adding the parsing outside XPath. It doesn't look that bad and it is actually the only way to go. Of course, you could extract that into some methods to perform the field extraction and parsing and it will look better.

More detail on why XPath 2.0 is not supported: Actually, it is that HtmlUnit is not supporting XPath 2.0. It is just that XPath is being handled in `org.apache.xpath.*` and it currently does not support 2.0. If support for the newer XPath version is added there then you will be able to use XPath 2.0 expressions in the `getByXPath` and `getFirstByXPath` methods.

Comment: Has anything changed?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `//a[@class='someclass']/number()` is legal in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0 so you would need to ensure your Java application plugs in an XPath 2.0 engine like Saxon 9  if you want to use that syntax. But I doubt that the API you are using (like `getByXPath`) is designed with XPath 2.0 in mind and allows you to return sequences of values for instance. JAXP allows you to plug in Saxon instead of Xalan but its API does nevertheless then not allow you to return sequences of primitive values.

So often you need to change more than the XPath engine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I didn't know about Saxon.If it supports XPath 2 i'll go for it.Strange thing that its not allow to return sequences of primitive values.I'm wondering `//a[@class='someclass']/number()` what would return...

Comment: In XPath 2.0 and in XQuery `//a[@class='someclass']/number()` returns a sequence of double number values and Saxon's own API certainly allows you to evaluate such expressions and process such values. Only the JAXP XPath API that Saxon also supports is not suitable to deal with the richness of the type system of XPath 2.0.

Comment: I've experienced a little with Saxon and it seems to go fine with xml only.So then i spend most of the time to convert html to xml using htmlunit and jtidy.This seems to be a very hard case and i didn't get the results i was expecting.There are many ψονδιτιονσ to conform an html page to a well formed xml required by Saxon.Just wondering if i miss something about Saxon's XPath 2.0 implementation.Is it for xml only?

Comment: Well `XPath` has the `X` in its name due to being an `XML Path Language` so by its definition and specification an implementation of XPath is meant to work with XML. On the other hand Saxon is not an XML parser itself, it uses an XML parser like Xerces and the Java architecture allows you to plug in an HTML parser like TagSoup (http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/ instead of an XML parser.

Comment: Ok, i got that the `X` factor is for XML. I was just asking because i didn't face such complications about html with XPath 1.0 and Xalan. I appreciate your help.